# Mode line not working even if everything seems correct

Tags: modeline

I'm editing a file with the following pattern:

```
# stock comment
# stock comment
# stock comment
# stock comment
# stock comment

conf
conf

conf
conf

very_long_conf_line_xxxxxx (600+ chars)
```

It's the stock layout and the file name ends with `.conf`, so Vim picked it up with `ft=conf`. It's actually some Nginx configuration, so I inserted a modeline like this:

```
# stock comment
# stock comment
# stock comment
# stock comment
# stock comment
# vim: set filetype=nginx:

conf
conf

conf
conf

very_long_conf_line (600+ chars)
```

However, when opening the file again, it's still taken as `ft=conf`.

`:verbose se ml?` shows `modeline` and last set from `~/.vimrc line xx`, and `:verbose se ft?` shows `filetype=conf` and last set from `/usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim`.

Why isn't my mode line working? How do I get it to work?

I'm running Vim 8.1 from Ubuntu Eoan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim only checks for "a number of lines at the beginning of the end of the file". By default, only the first and last 5 lines are checked.

From `:help 'modeline'`:

> If 'modeline' is on 'modelines' gives the number of lines that is
>       checked for set commands

And from `help: 'modelines'`:

> 'modelines' 'mls'  number  (default 5)

If you wish, you can

- `:set modelines` to a larger number, or
- place the modeline(s) at the beginning or end of the file.

Comment: Well... if only the stock comment contained one less line :(